# WP Admin defaiult Menu order order number

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Can i see the Default Menu order number ?
Ex : 
i've added a create new menu code like this : 
add_menu_page('Slide Images', 'Slide Images',8,'LDEasy-Slideshow/slide.php','', '',5);

but it's replace POST Menu... 
Anybody can halp me describe the order of menus in wordpress ?!

Answer (score 0):

The position in which the menu appears is the last item (5) in your case. This is an optional parameter and you can remove it, which essentially will bring your plugin/template/page to be the last in the list and it willnot overwrite any of the existing pages.

Comment: but when i want to place my costumize menu not in the last menu, i must fill the position in add_menu_page. so i need to know the default menu positions for when i add new customize menu, it's will not break the default wordpress menu. can you explain that ?